# SWT Table not scrolling with mouse wheel

Tags: java, swt

I am creating a JFace table like this:

```
final Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
```

And was expecting scrolling (with the headers fixed at the top), but I am not getting what I expected. There are both vertical and horizontal scrollbars with which I can scroll the table, but

1. The column headers scroll out of view
2. I can't scroll with my mouse wheel even when it's in focus.

Do I really need to add that myself?

ETA more detail:

I am using my table as the details part of a MasterDetails Block.

My DetailsPage class extends AbstractFormPart and implements IDetailsPage.

```
@Override
public void createContents(final Composite parent) {
    final Layout layout = new FillLayout();
    parent.setLayout(layout);
    createViewer(parent);

}
    private void createViewer(final Composite parent) {
        final Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

//      this.viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | /*SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL |*/ SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
        this.viewer = new TableViewer(table);
        createColumns(parent, this.viewer);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

        this.viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
        // get the content for the viewer, setInput will call getElements in the
        // contentProvider
        this.viewer.setInput( /createInput() );
        // make the selection available to other views
        this.editor.getSite().setSelectionProvider(this.viewer);
        ...
    }
```

createInput() returns an array of my elements. The commented out part was my initial attempt that was also not working.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I get fixed headers and I can scroll with the mouse wheel. Which OS are you using? Can you post the complete code snippet where you create your table?

Comment: @Baz I added the code. Can you reproduce it now?

Comment: @Baz I'm on Windows 7, Eclipse Juno

Comment: Nope, can't reproduce it. [Here](http://pastebin.com/kZWr9NhD) is what I usually do. Works just fine. I'm not using RCP though.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the way my master/details block is set up? The master section (a treeview) scrolls just fine when the focus is on it. Also, I noticed that when the list is really long, the horizontal scrollbar (if there is one) is all the way at the bottom and I have to scroll all the way down to see it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. As I said, I don't use RCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this worked, but when I changed the layout of the details page to a GridLayout and gave the table the following GridData, it worked as expected.

```
    final GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    gd.widthHint = 500;
    gd.heightHint = 120;
    table.setLayoutData(gd);
```

I got the tip from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/106635/)